# Passing JavaScript values into Java GWT

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, jsni

I need to return a value from JSNI GWT method like so:

```
    public native int connect(String macAdress) /*-{

    var result = 0;
    $wnd.bluetoothSerial.connect(macAdress, function() {
        $wnd.console.log("connect success");
        result = 1 ;
    }, function() {
        $wnd.console.log("Failed connect");
    });
    return result;
}-*/;
```

form some reasons it return 0 even if the connection successful. Apparently this variable keep the default value,
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling an asychronous method and can't return a value that way.

You will need to pass an Callback into your native code:

See [Pass Java Callback Function to JSNI Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407957/pass-java-callback-function-to-jsni-method)